# Using IPV6 in Hetzener under KVM virtualization

Tags: ipv6

I have a VPS which is being managed with SolusVM + KVM in Hetzener data-center. I got one IPv6 but don't know how set it up. I tried this, did not work for Debian 7 64 bit:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:4f8:192:342e::xxxx:xxxx
netmask 64
gateway 2a01:4f8:192:342e::0000:0001
```

Answer (score 1):

Hetzner have different hosting products. The IPv6 configuration required for these differs in some aspects. You haven't mentioned exactly which of their solutions you have.

I have some VPS from their VQ product line. On those each VPS get a `/64` link prefix and no routed prefix. The gateway address inside the link prefix ends with `::1`. Your specified gateway address would be correct for such a VPS. However if that was the case `2a01:4f8:192:342e::1` would have responded to traffic from outside - which it does not.

I have some dedicated servers from their SB product line. Those also get a `/64` link prefix. I do not know if routed prefixes are available for these. On those the gateway address is not chosen from within the link prefix, rather the gateway address is `fe80::1` regardless of what the link prefix is.

Comment: I assume a /64 is assigned to the main server. The provider installed KVM along with SolusVM and installed a VPS for me on it.

Comment: @Amin For such a setup they should really be giving you both a link prefix for the connection between host and router and a routed prefix which can be used for link prefix(es) on the virtual link(s) between host and VPS. Another possibility is to do it with a single link prefix by bridging all the virtual links to the physical link. You need to show us the configuration on the host before we'll be able to say much more.